# Centering text with clear after two floats

Tags: css-float, centering

Two questions for [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlesko/j7ty8/10/)...

1. Why doesn't the `middle` text move under the `left` and `right` texts even though it has `clear: both` assigned to it?
2. Why doesn't the `middle` text go to the middle of the footer even with `margin: 0 auto`?

I did manage to get the text to the middle under `left` and `right` but I had to use a separate `div` around the `<h7 id="middle">`. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be more precise. `<h7>` doesn't exist, so it is rendered as an inline element... So `clear` doesn't affect it!

(And you'll have to use `text-align:center;` instead of `margin:auto;`, unless you use a specified width)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't exist? Like it's not an object or what?
So the only solution is to put it inside a div?

Comment: h7 is not in any html DTD. So it doesn't exist. http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_heading

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.
I changed it to `h5` and added `text-align: center;` and it works!
Thank you...